# JavaFx: Label text doesn't wrap

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a `BorderPane` with `Pane`s for left, right and center elements and `HBox` for top element. On the right `Pane` there is a `Label`. The `Label` contains some text, which doesn't wrap and therefore gets cut.

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    private static BorderPane gamePane;
    private static Pane cellsPane;
    private static HBox buttonsPane;
    private static Pane statsPane;
    private static Pane setupsPane;

    Label cellsCountLabel;    

    static int  gameWidth= 700;
    static int gameHeight=600;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        gamePane = new BorderPane();

        buttonsPane = new HBox(5);
        statsPane = new Pane();
        cellsPane = makeGrid(20);
        setupsPane = new Pane();

        cellsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #ffffff; -fx-border-color: black");
        buttonsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #f2f2f2; -fx-border-color: black");
        statsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #f2f2f2; -fx-border-color: black");
        setupsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #f2f2f2; -fx-border-color: black");

        cellsPane.setMaxWidth(400);
        statsPane.setMaxWidth((gameWidth-400)/2);
        setupsPane.setMaxWidth((gameWidth-400)/2);

        createCellButton = new Button();
        deleteCellsButton = new Button();

        createCellButton.setText("Create a cell");
        deleteCellsButton.setText("Delete cells");

        ...

        buttonsPane.setSpacing(10);
        buttonsPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        buttonsPane.getChildren().add(createCellButton);
        buttonsPane.getChildren().add(deleteCellsButton);

        gamePane.setTop(buttonsPane);
        gamePane.setCenter(cellsPane);

        ...

        cellsCountLabel = new Label("Cells Count: " + (cellId + 1));
        statsPane.getChildren().add(cellsCountLabel);
        gamePane.setLeft(statsPane);

        setupsPane.getChildren().add(new Label("Setups Panel1111115552222222133331111"));
        gamePane.setRight(setupsPane);

        gamePane.setMargin(statsPane, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        gamePane.setMargin(cellsPane, new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        gamePane.setMargin(setupsPane, new Insets(0,0,0,0));

        statsPane.setPrefWidth(150);
        setupsPane.setPrefWidth(150);

        cellsCountLabel.setWrapText(true);  //doesn't work

        Scene scene = new Scene(gamePane, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        ...

        primaryStage.show();
}
...
}
```

However, there exists space between left, center and right `Pane`s. The space gets smaller as the content in those `Pane`s get larger, however, when it gets too large it messes with the center `Pane`.

[image]

I tried using `cellsCountLabel.setWrapText(true)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344916/wrapping-label-text-in-a-vbox-using-fxml.

Comment: You must set prefWidth.

Comment: @Ralf Renz To `setupsPane` with `Label`? Already did... Or to the `Label` itself?

Comment: @Ralf Renz I tried `cellsCountLabel.setPrefWidth(150);` but it didn't make a change..

Comment: It looks like the label for which you set wrapping doesn't need to wrap, so why should it? On the longer label you don't set wrap, so it doesn't wrap.  If you want your center pane to always be at least 400 pixels wide, why don't you call `setMinWidth` on it?

Comment: cellsCountLabel is the label on the left side. The label on the right side has yet no variable. You must extract it from the line setupsPane.getChildren().add(new Label("Setups Panel1111115552222222133331111"));.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Label label = new Label("Setups Panel1111115552222222133331111");
label.setWrapText(true);
label.setMaxWidth((gameWidth-400)/2);
setupsPane.getChildren().add(label);
```

Also if you go this route you may want to declare something like this

```
static double sidePaneWidth = (gameWidth-400)/2;
```

for later use

You can also make this into a function like so if necessary

```
private Label newSidePaneLabel(String labelString){
    Label label = new Label(labelString);
    label.setWrapText(true);
    label.setMaxWidth(sidePaneWidth);
    return label;
}
```